# ASP.NET Day Render Issue

Tags: asp.net, calendar

Can you have a look at the code below and tell me how I can fix this. Each time the day is rendered in the calendar, it calls a webservice (service.EventGetList("ALL")
). Its causing the page to very slow. How can I call the webservice only once, and still achieve the same results?

```
Protected Sub calendar1_DayRender(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Web.UI.WebControls.DayRenderEventArgs) Handles calendar1.DayRender

        WordFoundAt = -1    'not found

        'declare a new dataset
        Dim ds As New DataSet("MyDataSet")

        'declare a new datatable 
        Dim dTable As New DataTable("EventsData")

        'decalre a new datarow
        Dim dr As DataRow

        'assign all events from the webservice
        openEvents = service.EventGetList("ALL")

        'build the columns for the datatable
        dTable.Columns.Add("Id", GetType(String))
        dTable.Columns.Add("Title", GetType(String))
        dTable.Columns.Add("EventStart", GetType(DateTime))
        dTable.Columns.Add("EventEnd", GetType(DateTime))


        Dim dr1 As DataRow()

        ' ds.Tables.Add(dTable)
        Dim i As Integer = 0
        For Each currEvent In openEvents

            'assign local variables to the properties of the events in the array
            id1 = openEvents(i).id
            Title = openEvents(i).Title
            eventStart = openEvents(i).EventStart
            eventEnd = openEvents(i).EventEnd


            dr = dTable.NewRow()

            dr.Item("Id") = id1
            dr.Item("Title") = Title
            dr.Item("EventStart") = eventStart
            dr.Item("EventEnd") = eventEnd


            dTable.Rows.Add(dr)

            i = i + 1

        Next

        'do a select on the datatable and filter the results to give you the events for the day of the cell 
        ' as this method gets executed every time the cell is created, the calender control creates the cells 1 x1

        dr1 = dTable.Select(String.Format("EventStart >= #{0}# AND EventStart < #{1}#", e.Day.Date.ToLongDateString(), e.Day.Date.AddDays(1).ToLongDateString()))

        'local counter variables
        Dim x As Integer = 0
        Dim y As Integer = 0
        Dim a As String

        'loop to add all available event dates to an array
        For Each dr In dr1
            datearray(y) = dr.Item("EventStart")
            idarray(y) = dr.Item("Id")
            y = y + 1
        Next

        'delcare variables for flag true/false

        'loop 
        For Each dr In dr1

            'pull event date from previous array and assign it to local variable
            a = datearray.GetValue(x)

            'assign current event date to local variable WordToFind
            WordToFind = dr.Item("EventStart")


            ' test if the current event date = what ever is in the array of events and the flag is false

            If WordToFind = a Then

                'if the cell has a control on it (i.e the Image of the X) 
                If Not e.Cell.Controls.Count > 1 Then


                    e.Cell.CssClass = "event"



                Else


                End If

            End If

            x = x + 1

        Next

    End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The event you are using is called `DayRender` it happens when each Day is rendered.  I am also not quite sure what your web service is doing, but if you don't want it called each time.  Move the call outside of the event and store it as a local field.  You can do it on `Page_Init` to have it be called before you controls are rendered.